# Twitter access token and access secret is returning null exception after changing to twitter api version 1.1 in android?

Tags: android, twitter

First I am able to login with twitter button with twitter4j-core jar version 2.1.11 and able to retrieve access token and secret. But after twitter has stopped the functionality of API version 1 I have added new twitter4j-core jar version 3.0.3 with API version 1.1. Now I am not able to retrieve the access token and access secret.

Here is database method where I have stored my access token and access secret.

```
 public static void save(Context context, final OAuthConsumer oAuthConsumer) {
    SharedPreference.storeValue(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, oAuthConsumer.getToken(), context);
    SharedPreference.storeValue(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, oAuthConsumer.getTokenSecret(), context);
}
```

Another Database method where I am retrieving the stored values as:

```
public static AccessToken retrieveStoredAccessToken(Context context)
{
    String token = SharedPreference.getValueFromStore(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN , context);
    String secret = SharedPreference.getValueFromStore(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, context);
    return new AccessToken(token, secret);
}
```

Now when user clicks the login button it will redirect to method isAuthenticated() where I am retrieve stored access token and secret

```
public static boolean isAuthenticated(Context context) 
{
    try
    {   
        AccessToken accessToken = Database.retrieveStoredAccessToken(context); // String token and secret is received null from databse
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
        twitter.getAccountSettings();
        return true;
    }
    catch (TwitterException e)
    {   
        System.out.println("Twitter Authenticated : false");
        return false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {       
        System.out.println("Twitter Authenticated : false");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Access token returns Null Exception. I am able to login with twitter but session is not stored because of access token and access secret throws null exception.

following jar file use

1) signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
2) signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
3) twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured my problem.

Just need to change these things:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?force_login=true from http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate
```